# сделать так, чтобы картинки при рандоме не повторялись

Tags: javascript

Есть 10 иконок. При загрузке страницы выбираю рандомную из них и показываю

```
   const id =  pictures[Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures.length)];
```

Далее при нажатии на кнопку "показать еще" нужно чтобы функция random уже искал рандомную среди оcтавшихся pictures и так далее, пока картинки не закончатся. Когда они закончатся, все повторяется снова. Ищем рандом из 10 картинок, из 9 и т.д.
Нужно сделать, чтобы картинки при рандоме не повторялись.
после того как выбрали все 10 иконок (рандомно), следующая картинка (одиннадцатая) не может совпасть с последней, выбранной из первой десятки

Comment: Уточните, после того как выбрали все 10 иконок (рандомно), следующая картинка (одиннадцатая) может совпасть с последней, выбранной из первой десятки?

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб:

1. Завести другой массив, из которого будем брать случайный элемент.
2. Когда он опустеет (или если он ещё пустой), то переносить все элементы из изначального массива картинок в него.
3. После нахождения случайного элемента, удалять элемент из этого массива.

Как-то так:

```
const picturesNotUsed = [];

function getRandomPicture() {
    if (picturesNotUsed.length === 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < pictures.length; ++i) {
            picturesNotUsed.push(pictures[i]);
        }
    }

    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * picturesNotUsed.length);
    const id =  picturesNotUsed[index];

    picturesNotUsed.splice(index, 1);

    return id;
}
```

Comment: Ваш рандом - не рандом, он притянут к критическим значениям функцией `Math.floor()`, более менее нормальный рандом будет так: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/random-int-min-max , абзац `Верное решение с round`

Comment: @ferrari я эту часть скопировал из вопроса.

Comment: @ferrari Наверное вы путаете с `Math.round(Math.random(range))`. Здесь как раз таки верный вариант (по вашей ссылке он идет как альтернативный правильный вариант).

Comment: По заданию не очевидно, но возможно требуется исключить повторы и после перехода на новую пачку из десяти картинок (в текущем варианте первая картинка из новой может совпасть с последней из предыдущей)..

Comment: А как исключить повторы?
Можно использовать эту формулу для рандома?
 Math.floor(Math.random() * picturesNotUsed.length);

Comment: @werty Как вариант - запоминать последнюю использованную картинку  и сразу после заполнения нового массива убирать её.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan может быть повторение через один или через два. что бы такого не был овообще надо повторять прошлый рендом полностью. Либо надо саму задачу переформулировать. Как вариант удалять последние N.

Comment: @werty так в моём коде и так все повторы исключены.

Comment: @Suvitruf после того как масив снова скопируется первое может случайно стать тем же что было в прошлом массиве последним.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин тогда поправьте вопрос, так как сейчас там про это условие ни слова.

Comment: уточнил вопрос!!

Comment: @werty теперь может через одну совпасть, то есть 10ая выбрана была, потом первая другая, а потом опять 10ая

Comment: Как мне переделать данный алгоритм, чтобы это максимально учитывать?

Answer (score 0):

Перемешать исходный массив определенное количество раз, и затем брать из него элементы по порядку

```
function swap (list){
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    let b = list[y];
    list[y] = list[x];
    list[x] = b;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) // сколько раз перемешать
    swap(arr);
```

UPD
Из комментария под предыдущим ответом: лучше использовать данную реализацию генератора случайных чисел

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }
```

Comment: Ну есть же нормальные алгоритмы перемешивания. И есть тупой с sort. Зачем городить вот эту вот штуку?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что у sort есть фатальный недостаток.

Comment: @Qwertiy это тупое решение в лоб, на коленке. Пример кода приведен не как образец идеального решения, а для понимания сути. Если человек умеет в алгоритмизацию - он сам выберет оптимальный для его ситуации алгоритм перемешивания.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  исходный массив с айдишниками картинок
var pictures_ids = [10, 12, 15];
var id;

//  "вредный код"
Array.prototype.nextElem = function() {
    if (typeof this.current === 'undefined') {
        this.current = 0;
        return this[this.current];
    }

    this.current++;

    if (typeof this[this.current] === 'undefined') {
        this.current = 0;
    }

    return this[this.current];
};

//  получаем массив айдишников в случайном порядке
var pictures_rand = pictures_ids;
pictures_rand.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});

//  теперь где-то при нажатии на кнопку "показать еще" достаточно вызвать код
id = pictures_rand.nextElem();
alert(id);
```

Этот код будет крутить элементы по кругу.
Но я бы не стал что-то писать в прототип, лучше вынести отдельной функцией.

Answer (score 0):

Upd.[Пример](https://codepen.io/Arver1/pen/bLeNbg):

```
<div class="a1 hidden"></div>
<div class="a2 hidden"></div>
<div class="a3 hidden"></div>
<div class="a4 hidden"></div>
<div class="a5 hidden"></div>
<button id="btn">Нажмите меня</button>
<style>
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.a1 {
    background: #FF0000;
}
.a2 {
    background: #8000FF;
}
.a3 {
    background: #1997FF;
}
.a4 {
    background: #00FF59;
}
.a5 {
    background: #EEFF00;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 70px;
}
</style>
<script>
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showImg(imgs);
});
function showImg(cll){
    if(showImg.count == cll.length) {
        showImg.count = 0;
    }
    if(showImg.count == 0) {
        showImg.arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(cll);
    }
    let currentImg = generateId(showImg.arr).next().value;
    if(showImg.hidden) showImg.hidden.classList.add('hidden');
    currentImg.classList.remove('hidden');
    showImg.count++;
    showImg.hidden = currentImg;
    console.log(currentImg);
}    
showImg.count = 0;
showImg.hidden = 0;
function* generateId(arr) {
        yield arr.splice(getRandomNumber(0, arr.length-1), 1)[0];
    }
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    if(max == 0) return 0;
    return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, где не выпадают последние пять иконок и приоритет отдается иконкам, которые давно не выпадали.

```js
const size = 10;
let weights = Array(size).fill(10); // Вероятности выпадения иконок, изначально равны.

// Возвращает индекс массива w с вероятностью, заданной значением элементов.
function randDistr(w) {
  let sum = w.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * sum);
  let i = 0;
  for (let s = w[0]; s <= rand; s += w[i]) {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

function getRndInx() {
  let w = weights.map(x => x >= 5 ? x : 0); // Копируем вероятности выпадения, исключая те, у которых вероятность меньше пяти.
  let i = randDistr(w);
  weights = weights.map(a => ++a); // Увеличиваем на единицу вероятности для всех иконок.
  weights[i] = 0; // Для выпавшей иконки обнуляем вероятность (не будет выпадать, пока не вырастет до пяти).
  return i;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
  console.log(getRndInx());
}
```